# Check if MKPolyline intersects MKPolygon

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm trying to figure out if a `MKPolyline` intersects an `MKPolygon` on map. Currently the only idea I have about this is to go through the line and test on every point if it is located in polygon. More exactly, I'm trying to test if there aren't any `MKPolygon` between `MKUserLocation` and an objective on map (so `MKUserLocation` can see that objective).

Any more practical idea about how to do this? If not, how to transform the MKPolyLine into a lot of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both conform to the MKOverlay protocol. You can use the property defined on the protocol called boundingMapRect, and use it on a protocol-defined method called intersectsMapRect. More info here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: If the MKPolygon was a circle the corners of the bounding rect would not actually contain the circle and wouldn't be blocking the view of the target. And for that matter a diagonal line's bounding rect contains a lot of open space that would intersect with nearby MKPolygons even though the line from corner to corner does not.

Comment: Yes, I just hit this issue today. Any idea about how I could approach this?

Comment: I have just created a new MKPolygon category. It takes two MKPolygons and creates a new MKPolygon based on the union of those two MKPolygons. the github link is: https://github.com/geeksweep/MKPolygon-MKPolygonIntersections  I know this is a late answer but I hope it is useful to you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am having problems with a polyline and a polygon where the bounding maprect intersects, but the two shapes don't. still, the intersectsMapRect returns true?!? Any idea?